# string array conversion

Tags: c, ansi-c

I have the following code:

```
char *array1[3] = 
{
    "hello",
    "world",
    "there."
};

struct locator_t
{
    char **t;
    int len;
} locator[2] =
{
    {
        array1,
        10
    }
};
```

It compiles OK with "gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic". But with another toolchain (Rowley), it complains about

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

on the line where char **t is. Is this indeed illegal code or is it OK?

Thanks for all the answer. I now know where my problem was. However, it raises a new question:

[string array initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834643/string-array-initialisation)

Comment: on wich line appears the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems perfectly legal to me; `char *[3]` decays to `char **`, so the assignment should be valid.

Neither GCC 4.4.5 nor CLang 1.1 complains.

Answer (score 2):

Although in practice `array1` should decay to a pointer of type `char **`, its real type is in fact `char *[3]`, hence the warning.

To suppress the warning, you could try casting it explicitly:

```
...
(char **) array1;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

array1 is `(char *)[3]`, which is semantically different from `char **`, although in the assignment it should be gracefully degraded to a `char **`

Answer (score -1):

Pointers and arrays and only compatible in static scope. In global scope a pointer and an array are not the same, mixing the two will result in undefined behavior. So in my opinion, the warning is correct.

Try putting:

```
extern char *array1[3] = 
{
    "hello",
    "world",
    "there."
};
```

in one module and:

```
extern char **array1;

struct locator_t
{
    char **t;
    int len;
} locator[2] =
{
    {
        array1,
        10
    }
};
```

in another, compile and link. (I haven't tried it…) I would expect things to go wrong...

Comment: Your first module doesn't compile because you can't declare a variable `extern` and initialize it in one statement. If you fix that, you might get linker errors because the declared types don't match.

Comment: Funny, my first module compiles with warnings but the seconds doesn't for the same reason as original question… That was a quick flash that went wrong, I wanted to underline the difference between arrays and pointers in global scope.