# string array initialisation

Tags: c, string, pointers, ansi-c

This is a continuation of another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834294/string-array-conversion) I have.

Consider the following code:

```
char *hi = "hello";

char *array1[3] = 
{
    hi,
    "world",
    "there."
};
```

It doesn't compile to my surprise (apparently I don't know C syntax as well as I thought) and generates the following error:

```
  error: initializer element is not constant
```

If I change the char* into char[] it compiles fine:

```
char hi[] = "hello";

char *array1[3] = 
{
    hi,
    "world",
    "there."
};
```

Can somebody explain to me why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first example (`char *hi = "hello";`), you are creating a non-const pointer which is initialized to point to the static const string "hello".  This pointer could, in theory, point at anything you like.

In the second example (`char hi[] = "hello";`) you are specifically defining an array, not a pointer, so the address it references is non-modifiable.  Note that an array can be thought of as a non-modifiable pointer to a specific block of memory.

Your first example actually compiles without issue in C++ (my compiler, at least).

Comment: thanks. is there a way to use the const keyword to make the 1st piece of code work?

Comment: @lang2 Not in that scope. See this [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constasconst.html). Not even with `char *const hi` (constant pointer to char).

Comment: Just added something, tho' I'm not sure if it will work... your first version compiles OK in C++ - I'll try with a C compiler when I get a moment :)

Comment: @icabod It won't. Read the link I posted.